# why ((size_t) &((TYPE *)0)->MEMBER) is not considered as constexpr since g++7.4

Tags: c++, gcc

following code can be compiled successfully in g++7.3

```
#include <iostream>
struct IMsg
{
    int i;
    int j;
};
int func()
{
    constexpr size_t offset = ((size_t)&(((IMsg*)0)->j));
    std::cout << offset << std::endl;
}
```

but since g++7.4, I always got the compilation error as below

```
main.cpp:44:75: error: dereferencing a null pointer in '*0'
 constexpr size_t offset = ((size_t)&(((IMsg*)0)->j));
                                                    ^
main.cpp:44:75: error: conversion from pointer type ‘uint16_t* {aka short unsigned int*}’ to arithmetic > type ‘size_t {aka long unsigned int}’ in a constant expression
```

if I remove constexpr before size_t, it can be compiled successfully.

I don't get why constexpr can't be used here as the result can sure  be known at compile time

and this is also the implementation of offsetof if builtin_offsetof is not provided.

Comment: I can't answer the question of why it gives an error where it didn't before, but I think an error is a good outcome.   You might want to reconsider the need for such an expression in the first place.   Since it dereferences a null (zero) pointer, it has undefined behaviour if it does compile.  Consider using the `offsetof()` macro that is defined in `<cstddef>` instead.

Comment: but once I removed constexpr, it can be compiled and it does dereference a null pointer, yet no error outcome

Comment: Dereferencing a null pointer is undefined behavior. "It looks like it works" is one form of undefined behavior. The code is still broken. Triggering undefined behavior inside what's supposed to be a constant expression makes it no longer a constant expression.

Comment: I remember that `offsetof()` used the trick with the NULL pointer as well but this might have been worked in the past only. It seems to be changed nowadays: [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b585ac732a326df9)

Comment: @Scheff  Yes, several implementations of `offsetof()` use the null pointer trick. There is nothing wrong with code that is part of an implementation (like a standard header bundled with a compiler) having undefined behaviour, since that code is inherently implementation-specific. It is, however, dangerous for user code - like that shown by the OP - to do such tricks.  It is also *unnecessary* for user code to emulate `offsetof()` using non-portable constructs since the standard guarantees `offsetof()` is available in *all* freestanding and hosted implementations.

Comment: what confuses me most is that why compiler only think it's an error when constexpr is present. and it's ok when constexpr is removed.